# May a woman be a Ba'alat Kriah (Torah reader) if no men know how?

Tags: women, torah-reading

I am a bit unclear regarding the full applications of *kavod hatzibbur* as it regards women being involved in certain aspects of prayer. I gather that one application of this rule disallows women from being *shlichot tzibbur* "cantors".

Suppose that there is a minyan, but none of the men know how to read from the Torah. A woman who is present is capable and is a "professional" (meaning, she is extremely competent in reading correctly with no errors or stumbling.) Is there a problem with allowing her to read the Torah? Or does *kavod hatzibbur* take precedence and we rather have a man read it with someone else reading the notes from a Chumash and having him follow?

What if none of the men present read Hebrew well or understand the trope? Can we allow the woman to read, or do we forego the Torah reading altogether b/c of *kavod hatzibbur*?

Comment: I believe the Hagahot Maimoniyot cites the Maharam M'Rotenberg that in a city/shul of kohanim (who are not called up after the first aliyah), women read the torah instead.

Comment: Related (dupe?): https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/69293/

Comment: @DonielF Slightly related but not dupe. Here, I'm asking for specific halacha *bish'at hadchak* ("emergency").